php dropdown list (code format) inside Javascript
I want to put inside Javascript a Select option value with data from php mysql Query (I already have input fields), This is my code:
 include "conexiondbpdo.php";
    function agregarDetalle(idarticulo,articulo,precio_venta,tasa){
        var cantidad=1;
    
        if (idarticulo!="") {
            var subtotal=cantidad*precio_venta;
            var fila=
                '<tr class="filas" id="fila'+cont+'">'+
                    '<td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle('+cont+')">X</button>
                    </td>'+
            '<td>
                <input type="hidden" name="idarticulo[]" value="'+idarticulo+'">'+articulo+'</td>'+
            '<td>
                <select  name="id_cuenta[]" class="form-control id_cuenta">
                    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
    <?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?>
                </select>
            </td>'+
            '<td><input type="number" name="cantidad[]" id="cantidad[]" value="'+cantidad+'"></td>'+
            '<td><input type="number" name="precio_venta[]" id="precio_venta[]" value="'+precio_venta+'"></td>'+
            '<td><span id="subtotal'+cont+'" name="subtotal">'+subtotal+'</span></td>'+
            '<td><button type="button" onclick="modificarSubtotales()" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></td>'+
            '</tr>';
            cont++;
            detalles++;
            $('#detalles').append(fila);
            modificarSubtotales();
            $("#tasa_cambio").val(tasa);
    
        }else{
            alert("error al ingresar el detalle, revisar las datos del articulo ");
        }
    }

This the php code for doing the mysql Query for populating the select option dropdown:
function fill_unit_select_box($connect)
{ 
    $output = '';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cuentas ORDER BY nombre ASC";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row["id_cuenta"].'">'.$row["nombre"].'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}

My pdo conection file(conexiondbpdo.php):
<?php
  //database connection

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=condominio", "root", "mysq1passw0rd");
?>

The php code inside javascript for populating drop down list is not working, I can see select option but not info populated in it:
'<td><select  name="id_cuenta[]" class="form-control id_cuenta"><option value="">Seleccione</option><?php echo fill_unit_select_box($connect); ?></select></td>'+

Please any ideas?

Do you see the options if you use View Source?

Try to code so you can read what you code. Dont pack everything into as small a space as possible. It makes nothin faster and slows down code maintenance a lot

You pass $connect to the function fill_unit_select_box($connect) BUT yu dont have access to that variable in function agregarDetalle(idarticulo,articulo,precio_venta,tasa){ where you call it from !!! So I think this is a variable scope issue

You may also benefit from some Error Processing on your PDO connection

I've got an include:  include "conexiondbpdo.php" there in conexiondbpdo.php I handle the mysql connection: $connect

@RiggsFolly agregarDetalle is a JS function, not PHP.

You need ?> before function agregarDetalle

I think php code inside javascript is wrong because code is in gray color: 'Seleccione Cuenta'+

The problem is the php code format inside the javascript-html table, I tried with a piece of the code and the php code and pdo worked, I have to fix the format in the whole code

Hi, I fixed the problem, it was that all code was in .js file, I didn't know that from .js file I cannot not use php code. I moved all to a .php file and that's worked
